# problems getting data from array

Tags: php

PHP From the xml file below I have to pickup 2 purchase prices including 2 quantities and put them into a table. The xml you see below. I can not get the needed vars out of the array.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><products>
<Product>
    <ParentName>22.01.14.10</ParentName>
    <Name>3040-100</Name>
    <Prices>
      <Price min-qty="1" currency="EUR">6,3200</Price>
      <Price min-qty="12" currency="EUR">5,3200</Price>
      <Price min-qty="24" currency="EUR">4,7200</Price>
   </Prices>
</Product>
<Product>
   <ParentName>22.01.10</ParentName>
   <Name>PDS1C</Name>
   <Prices>
      <Price min-qty="1" currency="EUR">1,9565</Price>
      <Price min-qty="10" currency="EUR">1,6828</Price>
      <Price min-qty="20" currency="EUR">1,4828</Price>
   </Prices>
</Product>
<Product>
   <ParentName>22.01.14</ParentName>
   <Name>P1017</Name>
   <Prices>
      <Price min-qty="1" currency="EUR">4,9337</Price>
      <Price min-qty="20" currency="EUR">3,9699</Price>
  </Prices>
</Product>
</products>
```

With this I fill the prices array:

```
foreach($product->{'Prices'}->children() as $key => $price)
{
$prices[ "" . $price->attributes()->{'min-qty'}] = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(',','.',"" . $price[0]));
}
ksort($prices); // sort array
```

Here the results:

```
Array
(
[1] => 6.3200
[12] => 5.3200
[24] => 4.7200
)
Array
(
[1] => 1.9565
[10] => 1.6828
[20] => 1.4828
)
Array
(
[1] => 4.9337
[20] => 3.9699
)
```

Now I have to fill the vars to put the vars into the table:

```
$qfirst = ''; // should be 1
$pfirst = ''; // should be 6.3200
$qsec = ''; // should be 12
$psec = ''; // should be 5.3200
```

What I try I do not get the data into the 4 vars.

Comment: `$product->{'Prices'}->children()` - wait, that syntax is valid?

Comment: @slugonamission It is unusual but it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @MathieuImbert - fair enough, I'd just never seen that syntax before and it's *very* weird.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
$prices[ "" . $price->attributes()->{'min-qty'}] = mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(',','.',"" . $price[0]));
```

To

```
$prices[] = array($price->attributes()->{'min-qty'},mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace(',', '.', "" . $price[0])));
```

Then

```
foreach(array_map(null,array("first","sec","third"),$prices) as $blend)
{
    ${"q". $blend[0]} = $blend[1][0];
    ${"p". $blend[0]} = $blend[1][1];
}

var_dump($qfirst,$pfirst,$qsec,$psec) ; // it would create this variables
```

OR

```
reset($prices);
foreach(array("first","sec","third") as $blend)
{
    ${"q". $blend} = key($prices);
    ${"p". $blend} = current($prices);
    next($prices);
}
var_dump($qfirst,$pfirst,$qsec,$psec) ;
```

Comment: Love this! Dynamic vars in PHP make it really flexible although a pain to debug :)

Comment: Baba; 100% score! Thanks. Finally a solution.

Comment: @user1575807 - Give him a +1 whilst your at it ;) It's a nice solution.

Comment: @webnoob you can warp it in a class making it easy to debug and access

Comment: @Baba - I agree but from a beginners point of view where they would be looking for `$myVar = "someVal"` then it's something very different :)

Comment: @webnoob if not for the naming convertion (extract)[http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php] would have been the best solution

Comment: @Baba - That's a nice function. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

for printing all the keys values. => `print_r(array_keys($array));`

for printing values =>     print_r(array_values($array));

Answer (score 0):

This simulates the first two rounds of a `foreach` loop and gives the desired result:

```
reset($prices);
$qfirst = key($prices);
$pfirst = current($prices);

next($prices);
$qsec = key($prices);
$psec = current($prices);
```